# how can I optimize this bisection, in F#

Tags: optimization, f#

I have the following bisection code:

```
let rec bisect (f: decimal -> decimal) (low: decimal) (high: decimal) (threshold: decimal) : decimal =
    let midPoint = (low + high) / 2.0m
    match high - low >= threshold with
    | true when sign(f low) * sign(f midPoint) > 0 ->
        bisect f midPoint high threshold
    | true ->
        bisect f low midPoint threshold
    | false ->
        midPoint
```

It takes a function that outputs a value that goes around 0 for the target input.
For example:

```
let func x = x - 35m

bisect func 0m 100m 1m
```

The problem with this code arises when the function is costly because the value at 'low' will be evaluated twice. For example:

```
let func x =
    printfn $"evaluating {x}"
    x - 35m

bisect func 0m 100m 1m
```

will return:

```
evaluating 0
evaluating 50
evaluating 0
evaluating 25
evaluating 25
evaluating 37.5
evaluating 25
evaluating 31.25
evaluating 31.25
evaluating 34.375
evaluating 34.375
evaluating 35.9375
evaluating 34.375
evaluating 35.15625
```

You can see that 6 evaluations out of 14 (roughly 40%) are duplicates, with the problem being at `sign(f low)`.

How can I rewrite this to avoid that problem?
I thought about have a lastLowResult option type and pass it in the loop so I could skip calculating it again if it is there, but that feels a bit clunky.

---

Edit:
here is the printout of the boundaries during the iterations:

```
low:0, high:100
evaluating 0
evaluating 50
low:0, high:50
evaluating 0
evaluating 25
low:25, high:50
evaluating 25
evaluating 37.5
low:25, high:37.5
evaluating 25
evaluating 31.25
low:31.25, high:37.5
evaluating 31.25
evaluating 34.375
low:34.375, high:37.5
evaluating 34.375
evaluating 35.9375
low:34.375, high:35.9375
evaluating 34.375
evaluating 35.15625
low:34.375, high:35.15625
```

Comment: Why do you need to compute `f low` at all? Shouldn't `f low < 0` be an invariant of the algorithm?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin, it's not: I edited the question with a printout of the low / high boudary values.

Comment: At all points in that printout, `f low` is definitely negative.

Comment: Think about it from a different perspective: as currently coded, what would `bisect` do if both `f low` and `f midPoint` were positive?

Comment: ahh, yes, I see, you are right, I can change the test to sign(f midPoint) < 0!

Comment: @FyodorSoikin, just tested and it works; thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: Here's another hint, but it's a secret, don't tell anybody: `sign(x) < 0` is equivalent to `x < 0`

Comment: hahah, that's what happens when code gets modified many times without paying attention :D

Comment: For every recursive call, you call `f` twice for low and mid-point. As you always keep one of hose values there is always one value computed twice. But if the computation is not expensive, there is no problem with computing something twice. That's what computers do. Adding a cache only makes sense if the computation is expensive and outweights the costs of a cache. The cache also costs memory and time. If you still want this, search for the term "Memoization".

Comment: @DavidRaab, yes that's a rather expensive call which is why, despite the low number of iterations, I wanted to minimize calls to. I thought about passing the last results as parameters in the loop, mentioned in the question. But since I was focused on how to solve that, I wasn't even looking closely at the inner loop and Fyodor spotted the issue right away. I didn't know the term Memoization, I'll look that up, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To avoid calling F multiple times you can memoize it (code by T. Petricek et al).

```
let memoize fn =
  let cache = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<_,_>()
  (fun x ->
    match cache.TryGetValue x with
    | true, v -> v
    | false, _ -> let v = fn (x)
                  cache.Add(x,v)
                  v)
```

and use it like this:

```
bisect (memoize func) 0m 100m 0.001m
```

On a different note, your code seems to go beyond the threshold. I think you want to stop if abs(f(x)) < threshold. The code below corrects this:

```
let rec bisect (f: decimal -> decimal) (low: decimal) (high: decimal) (threshold: decimal) : decimal =
    
    let midPoint = (low + high) / 2.0m

    match (abs(f midPoint)>=threshold) && (high - low)/2.0m >= threshold with
    | true when sign(f low) * sign(f midPoint) > 0 ->
        bisect f midPoint high threshold
    | true ->
        bisect f low midPoint threshold
    | false ->
        midPoint
```